# Mockito: mocking final class in UI tests

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, android-espresso

So starting with Android **P**, it is possible to mock final classes for UI / Espresso tests. Great.

After some research, I was using `com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito-inline-extended` to be able to mock final classes.

However, it uses and old version of mockito (`2.28.0` at the time of writing this post) while Mockito has recently released version `3.15.13`.

Up until now I was fine using an *old* version of Mockito until I stumbled on issues solved in later version.

The following gradle configuration:

```
androidTestImplementation "com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito-inline-extended:2.28.0"
androidTestImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0"
androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:3.5.13"
```

produces this error at compile time:

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker'.

I believe I know it means that some dependencies use the same dependency. I tried using exclude but without success.

Has anyone an idea on how to fix that ? Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2):

Removing `androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:3.5.13"` did it for me. They have an issue on their github https://github.com/linkedin/dexmaker/issues/149

Comment: Thank you but that is exactly my issue, meaning I can't use more recent versions of Mockito because `dexmaker:dexmaker` is way behind :(